# PHP: Is there any way to remove/delete specific text from A to B in one line?

Tags: php

**Not expected**

```
{"confirmed":39,"Deelae":0,"gjenoooom":0,"confirmedPer1kCapita":0.12839337095149364,"name":"Agder"},                
{"confirmed":116,"Deelae":0,"gjenoooom":0,"confirmedPer1kCapita":0.09397475967575468,"name":"Viken"},
```

**Expected**

```
{"confirmed":39,"Deelae":0,"gjenoooom":0,"name":"Agder"},                
{"confirmed":116,"Deelae":0,"gjenoooom":0,"name":"Viken"},
```

I tried a lots of methods to remove from "confirmedPer1kCapita" ***<:0.12839337095149364,>*** to "name"
i can remove by `$string = str_replace("<:0.12839337095149364,>","empty",$string);`, but there is a million lines like that.

Comment: it's much easier to use `json_decode()`, to `unset()` desire key and the to go back to JSON with `json_encode()`, no?

Comment: I'm not going to output. i just want to remove that part from JSON.

Comment: exactly. I'm not talking for any output here, just to modify the JSON.

Comment: You have a good point there. Can you come with an example code?

Comment: Why do you want to have it removed? Who is creating the JSON initially (and why don't you ask THIS person to remove the undesired properties in the first place)?

Comment: @LarsStegelitz it's from some other page that I want to web scrap and try to change some stuff there. and yeah I just want to know if there is away. in any case

Comment: @Zabkas, sure, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned as an comment, you can use `json_decode(), unset()` and back to JSON with `json_encode()`:

```
<?php
    //you need PHP Open SSL extension enabled to fetch this data.
    $json = file_get_contents('https://2strok.com/corona/norway.json');
    $arr = json_decode($json, true);
    print_r($arr);
    foreach ($arr['cases'] as $key => $sub_array) {
        print_r($sub_array);
        foreach ($sub_array as $k => $v) {
            if ($k = "confirmedPer1kCapita") {
                unset($arr['cases'][$key][$k]);
            }
        }
    }
    $output_json = json_encode($arr);
    echo $output_json;
```

Output:

```
//input array from the JSON
Array
(
    [totals] => Array
        (
            [confirmed] => 421
            [dead] => 0
            [recovered] => 1
        )

    [cases] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [confirmed] => 73
                    [dead] => 0
                    [recovered] => 0
                    [confirmedPer1kCapita] => 0.15416032251184
                    [name] => Rogaland
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [confirmed] => 40
                    [dead] => 0
                    [recovered] => 0
                    [confirmedPer1kCapita] => 0.1316855086682
                    [name] => Agder
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [confirmed] => 124
                    [dead] => 0
                    [recovered] => 0
                    [confirmedPer1kCapita] => 0.10045577758443
                    [name] => Viken
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [confirmed] => 51
                    [dead] => 0
                    [recovered] => 1
                    [confirmedPer1kCapita] => 0.074882060754312
                    [name] => Oslo
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [confirmed] => 27
                    [dead] => 0
                    [recovered] => 0
                    [confirmedPer1kCapita] => 0.072777457317369
                    [name] => Innlandet
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [confirmed] => 30
                    [dead] => 0
                    [recovered] => 0
                    [confirmedPer1kCapita] => 0.064646812912123
                    [name] => Trøndelag
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [confirmed] => 40
                    [dead] => 0
                    [recovered] => 0
                    [confirmedPer1kCapita] => 0.063331823924863
                    [name] => Vestland
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [confirmed] => 14
                    [dead] => 0
                    [recovered] => 0
                    [confirmedPer1kCapita] => 0.033671896232836
                    [name] => Vestfold og Telemark
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [confirmed] => 7
                    [dead] => 0
                    [recovered] => 0
                    [confirmedPer1kCapita] => 0.028697345495542
                    [name] => Troms og Finnmark
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [confirmed] => 5
                    [dead] => 0
                    [recovered] => 0
                    [confirmedPer1kCapita] => 0.018840055465123
                    [name] => Møre og Romsdal
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [confirmed] => 3
                    [dead] => 0
                    [recovered] => 0
                    [confirmedPer1kCapita] => 0.012328682680256
                    [name] => Nordland
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [confirmed] => 7
                    [dead] => 0
                    [recovered] => 0
                    [confirmedPer1kCapita] => 0
                    [name] => Ukjent
                )

        )

//final JSON
{
    "totals": {
        "confirmed": 421,
        "dead": 0,
        "recovered": 1
    },
    "cases": [{
        "confirmed": 73,
        "dead": 0,
        "recovered": 0,
        "name": "Rogaland"
    }, {
        "confirmed": 40,
        "dead": 0,
        "recovered": 0,
        "name": "Agder"
    }, {
        "confirmed": 124,
        "dead": 0,
        "recovered": 0,
        "name": "Viken"
    }, {
        "confirmed": 51,
        "dead": 0,
        "recovered": 1,
        "name": "Oslo"
    }, {
        "confirmed": 27,
        "dead": 0,
        "recovered": 0,
        "name": "Innlandet"
    }, {
        "confirmed": 30,
        "dead": 0,
        "recovered": 0,
        "name": "Tr\u00f8ndelag"
    }, {
        "confirmed": 40,
        "dead": 0,
        "recovered": 0,
        "name": "Vestland"
    }, {
        "confirmed": 14,
        "dead": 0,
        "recovered": 0,
        "name": "Vestfold og Telemark"
    }, {
        "confirmed": 7,
        "dead": 0,
        "recovered": 0,
        "name": "Troms og Finnmark"
    }, {
        "confirmed": 5,
        "dead": 0,
        "recovered": 0,
        "name": "M\u00f8re og Romsdal"
    }, {
        "confirmed": 3,
        "dead": 0,
        "recovered": 0,
        "name": "Nordland"
    }, {
        "confirmed": 7,
        "dead": 0,
        "recovered": 0,
        "name": "Ukjent"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so it's the same method with file_get_contents ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking? In general, yes, you could fetch the data with `file_get_contents()` from somewhere into a variable and then to sanitize to the desired content.

Comment: What I'm trying to get is the content of this page https://2strok.com/corona/norway.json
but in JSON and delete that part.

Comment: No worries. As this URL is https, you just need to enable `php_openssl` extension in your php.ini and then to fetch the JSON like: `$json = file_get_contents('https://2strok.com/corona/norway.json');` Just be aware that the JSON structure there is a bit different, but I'm sure you will figure out how to play with `cases` array from there.

Comment: I'm quite new in PHP,  Could you please recode that and use fetch? I would like the result back in JSON. THANKS @mitkosoft

Comment: @Zabkas, sure, see updated code with the real data.

Answer (score 1):

A possibel approach (as @mitkosoft mentioned in the comments) is the following example. Of course, you need to be sure, that each line is a valid JSON:

Code:

```
<?php
$text = '{"confirmed":39,"Deelae":0,"gjenoooom":0,"confirmedPer1kCapita":0.12839337095149364,"name":"Agder"}';
$json = json_decode($text, false);
unset($json->confirmedPer1kCapita);
$text = json_encode($json);

echo $text;
?>
```

Result:

```
{"confirmed":39,"Deelae":0,"gjenoooom":0,"name":"Agder"}
```